# Making 2nd Degree Polys Given a Triplet

Tags: perl

The purpose of this code is to make a subroutine that takes three coefficients k2, k1 , and k0 and returns an anonymous function/subroutine that takes one argument x and returns a string representation of the second degree polynomial with the given coefficients and its value at x, i.e., k2*x^2 + k1*x + k0.

As of right now, it returns the message "Can't use string ("6") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" is in use"

Does anyone see what I'm messing up?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0; 

sub make_2nd_degree_poly {
    my($k2, $k1, $k0) = @_;
    my $n = $_[0]; 
    return sub { 
        return ($k2 . 'x^2 . ' . $k1 . 'x + ' . $k0 . ' at x = ' . $n,
                $k2 * $n ** 2 + $k1 *$n + $k0
        );
    }
}

my @triplet0 = (1, 2, 3);
my @triplet1 = (4, 5, 6);
my $p1 = make_2nd_degree_poly(@triplet0);
my $p2 = make_2nd_degree_poly(@triplet1);
print "@{$p1->(1)}\n";
print "@{$p2->(2)}\n";
```

Next part of the issue: I need to write a function/sub gen_2nd_deg_polys that takes a list of 3-tuples and returns a list of anonymous 2nd
degree polynomials.

```
polys = gen_2nd_deg_polys([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
```

THIS SHOULD BE MY OUTPUT:

```
('1x^2 + 2x + 3 at x = 1 is ', 6)

('4x^2 + 5x + 6 at x = 2 is ', 32)
```

How can I extend this program to accomplish this task?

```
     sub gen_2nd_deg_polys { 
    return map(make_2nd_degree_poly(@{$_}), @_);
}
my (@a) = @_;
@a = ([1..3],[4..6]);
my @p3 = gen_2nd_deg_polys(@a);
print @p3->(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dereference something that's not a reference. Your created sub returns a list, make it return an anonymous array instead:

```
    return sub {
        [ "${k2}x^2 . $k1 x + $k0 at x = $n",
          $k2 * $n ** 2 + $k1 *$n + $k0 ]
    }
```

Or, return just one string:

```
    return sub {
        "${k2}x^2 . $k1 x + $k0 at x = $n "
        . ($k2 * $n ** 2 + $k1 *$n + $k0)
    }
```

Then, you need no dereference:

```
print $p1->(1), "\n";
print $p2->(2), "\n";
```

### Update

Or, return a list, no dereference needed in such a case, but you might like to add a space in between the formula and the result:

```
    return sub {
        my $n = $_[0];
        return "${k2}x^2 . $k1 x + $k0 at x = $n",
            ($k2 * $n ** 2 + $k1 *$n + $k0)
    }
# ...
print join ' ', $p1->(1), "\n";
print join ' ', $p2->(2), "\n";

sub gen_2nd_deg_polys {
    return map make_2nd_degree_poly(@$_), @_;
}

my @arr = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]);
my @p3 = gen_2nd_deg_polys(@arr);
print join ' ', $_->(1), "\n" for @p3;
```

Comment: This is very helpful, and works, except for that my second $n is read as "4", when it should be 2.

Comment: @TerikBrunson: You need the `my $n = $_[0]` inside the `sub {...}`.

Comment: I'm going to edit the original, as there is more to this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually, you should ask a new question as a new question.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the website tells me that I need to wait 90 minutes :(

Comment: `gen_2nd_deg_polys` returns a list, don't capture the return value in a scalar.

Comment: When I do this, it says "Can't use string("2") as a subroutine ref

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90705/discussion-between-terik-brunson-and-choroba).

Answer (score 0):

You can use references to force Perl to interpolate the return value of a function call inside double-quoted strings.So, here your `@{}` should contain `[]` to perl interpolate that you are returning an array reference.

You should do `@{[]}` in `print` to tell it you are returning an array reference which you are dreferencing using `@{}`.

Change your `print` statements to this. And then it should work:

```
print "@{[$p1->(1)]}\n";
print "@{[$p2->(2)]}\n";
```